# Getting distinct count of column on a SQLAlchemy query object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object, is it possible to count distinct column on it? I am asking because `.count()` returns dupes due to the join conditions.

For instance:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, distinct
channels = db.session.query(Channel).join(ChannelUsers).filter(
               ChannelUsers.user_id == USER_ID,
               Message.channel_id.isnot(None)
).outerjoin(Message)

# this gives us a number with duplicate channels 
# and .count() does not take extra parameters to target on column
channels.count()
...
# later on I need to access all these channels via channels.all()
```

To get a distinct channels count, I can do this by duplicating the filter condition above again and query the distinct column. Something like this

```
distinct_count = db.session.query(
    func.count(distinct(Channel.id))
).join(ChannelUsers).filter(
    ChannelUsers.user_id == USER_ID,
    Message.channel_id.isnot(None)
).outerjoin(Message)
```

But that's not ideal as I need to access some or all channels after getting the distinct count.

Answer (score 0):

Found this looking for the answer myself. After some more research, I was able to get the expected result using a combination of load_only and distinct in order to count only distinct values of an ID field. Let's say for simplicity that Channel has a unique field named id.

```
distinct_count = channels.options(load_only(Channel.id)).distinct().count()
```